# Take the error result and transform it to custom error class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, json.net

I have an HttpClient.PostAsync method and i want to convert the error response into a custom ErrorResponse class.

The response from the call:

```
{
    "ResponseStatus": {
        "ErrorCode": "NotFound",
        "Message": "Product does not exist in the system.",
        "Errors": []
    }
}
```

Custom Error class:

```
public class ErrorResponse
{
    string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    string Message { get; set; }
    Array Errors { get; set;}
}
```

How the call and conversion is done:

```
response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://testcall.com/", new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();
var m = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(m);
errorResponse =o.Value<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject("ResponseStatus").ToObject<ErrorResponse>();
```

ErrorResponse object properties remain null

Comment: What's this `var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(m)`? It should be either `dynamic o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(m)` or `var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(m)`, where `Response` is `class Response { ErrorResponse ResponseStatus; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with your code.

First, the properties of the `ErrorResponse` class must be `public` otherwise the deserializer will ignore them:

```
public class ErrorResponse
{
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Array Errors { get; set;}
}
```

Second, you cannot have a property of the abstract type `Array` because the deserializer doesn't know what concrete type has to create. Use a concrete type like `string[]` or some other class that represents your data type:

```
public class ErrorResponse
{
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string[] Errors { get; set;}
}
```

Third, the entire deserialization code could be rewritten as:

```
var r = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JObject>();
var errorResponse = r["ResponseStatus"].ToObject<ErrorResponse>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it using this

```
public class ErrorWrapper
{
    public ErrorResponse ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Then use this class while deserializing

```
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://testcall.com/", new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ErrorWrapper>(result);
```